# How to POST value data from <option> in PHP?

Tags: php, html

All code works when it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["lang"])) { $_SESSION["lang"] = "pl"; }
if (isset($_POST["lang"])) { $_SESSION["lang"] = $_POST["lang"]; }

require "translations/" . $_SESSION["lang"] . ".php";
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?=$_TXT[0]?></title>
    </head>
    <body lang="<?=$_SESSION["lang"]?>">
        <form method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="lang" value="en"/>
            <input type="submit" name="lang" value="pl"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to change input in a form to select and options how can I do that?

Comment: WARNING: Using direct user input to include files is a big security risk

Comment: Your session won't kick in because you are already outputing to the browser. Move all your php lines before your html.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your two inputs with this html:

```html
<form method="post">
  <select name="lang">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="pl">Polish</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Note: your PHP session will not work as you are already outputing html to the browser. Also, as mentioned by [@DarkBee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446594/darkbee) , it's a HUGE security risk to include a file based on user input, you need to make sure you control these inputs. Here is an alternative

```php
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["lang"])) { $_SESSION["lang"] = "pl"; }
if (isset($_POST["lang"]) && in_array($_POST["lang"], array('en','pl')) { 
    $_SESSION["lang"] = $_POST["lang"]; 
}

require "translations/" . $_SESSION["lang"] . ".php";
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body lang="<?=$_SESSION["lang"]?>">
        <form method="post">
<select name="lang">
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="pl">Polish</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `you need to make sure you control these inputs.` I dare to say "good luck with that" ;) You should never blindly trust data that comes from outside.

Comment: i recorded fast video to show you it is not working:  https://imgur.com/a/nsfn2h2

Comment: @G1nd3kk it is "not working", because you are not actually submitting your form. Before, you had _submit buttons_ that you clicked on. Selecting an option does not submit a form; if you want that to happen automatically as soon as a selection is made/changed, you need to use additional JavaScript for that.

Comment: @CBroe Can you show this js?

Comment: Please do a bit of research first, when someone mentions something you are not familiar with yet. _"submit form when option selected"_ or similar typed into Google, will get you plenty of result.